# 'UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification' calling twice for several devices\simulators

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, ios17

I have noticed strange behavior for `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification` on different devices/simulators. It seems that iPhone 15 Pro (both simulator and device) is calling callback twice for `willResignActiveNotification` on lock action. Example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(testCallback), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func testCallback() {
        // this message will be printed 2 times on iPhone 15 Pro with a small delay
        print("[willResignActiveNotification]")
    }
}
```

And it works as expected on other devices (e.g. iPhone 15). I also noticed that it
only reproduces on iOS 17, so it's probably a system bug. I'll  report it to Apple.
Is anyone else experiencing this problem?